# Accessing a global variable from a module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some code stored in a module which needs to access a global variable from whatever environment it is run in. This might seem like (might even be!) a slightly illogical structure, but a global variable with the same name is always created in any circumstance where I'm using this code. Unfortunately, I can't actually make it work. If I create the code all in the same file then it's fine:

```
DATE_TODAY = '2018-08-02'

class test_class:
    def __init__(self):
        print(DATE_TODAY)

t1 = test_class()
```

gives me 2018-08-02 as the output. However, if I move test_class to a module and then import it:

```
import Modules.test_mod as mod

DATE_TODAY = '2018-08-02'

t1 = mod.test_class()
```

I get this:

NameError: name 'DATE_TODAY' is not defined

I've played around using the global keyword to see if that helps, but it doesn't, so far as I can tell. Can anybody offer any advice?

Comment: A Python `import` does not work like an `include` in some other programming languages. You only import a reference, the code is still executed in the origin module.

Comment: Why not just pass the variable to `__init__`?

Comment: @Mad Physicist I can see why you'd say that, but it's a situation where I know that certain global variables (eg AS_OF_DATE) are always going to exist in the environment in which it's being used, so it's more practical not to have to pass them to every class/function.

Comment: Then import them into the module that the class or function is defined in.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying - like, mod.DATE_TODAY = DATE_TODAY?

Answer (score 2):

Your example runs fine with me. However you can define DATE_TODAY in the module and then import it to the other module, like below:

module m1.py:

```
   import m2 as mod
    from m2 import DATE_TODAY

    t1 = mod.test_class()
```

module m2.py:

```
DATE_TODAY = '2018-08-02'

class test_class:
    def __init__(self):
        print(DATE_TODAY)

    t1 = test_class()
```

output:

```
2018-08-02
2018-08-02
```

Comment: ... note though that module m1 is doing nothing with DATE_TODAY and you cannot define DATE_TODAY in module m1 as you will get circular conflicts [m1 importing from m2 and vice versa]

Comment: I think you can declare m1.DATE_TODAY = DATE_TODAY from your working environment (Jupyter in my case) - that seems to be the best solution.